# Как сделать страницу где будет считать 1000-7 до 6

Tags: javascript

```
    Типу:
1000-7=993
993-7=986
986-7=979
и т.д.
```

Comment: `let n =1000; while (n > 0) { console.log(n-=7) }`

Answer (score 1):

Допустим так

```js
let a = 1000, b = 7;
while(a-b >= 0) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `${a}-${b} = ${a = a-b}<br>`;
}
```

```css
body {font-size: 12px}
```

Ну или так

```js
let a = 1000, b = 7, 
    str = document.querySelector('#str'),
    ms = 150;

let timer = setTimeout(function tick() {
  if(a-b >= 0) {
    str.innerText = `${a}-${b} = ${a = a-b}`;
    timer = setTimeout(tick, ms);
  } else clearTimeout(timer);
}, ms);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="str"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так, например.

```html
<form oninput="result.value = `${+a.value + 7} - 7 = ${a.value}`" style="display:flex;font:20px sans-serif">
  <input type="range" name="a" max="993" min="6" step="7" value="993" style="flex:1 1 auto">
  <output name="result" style="width:7em;text-align:right">1000 - 7 = 993</output>
</form>
```